# Как сделать отправку сообщения раз в час, не останавливая polling? Py TeleBot

Tags: python, telebot, telethon, threading

Я пишу небольшого бота, который парсит сообщения из групп, отбирает нужные по ключевым словам и отсылает их в личку. Проблема в том, что нужно отсылать сообщение раз в час, помимо этого бот должен в это время продолжать принимать сообщения, то есть висеть в polling`е.  Вот код файла main, который есть на данный момент:

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient
import schedule
from threading import Thread
import time

from filter import filter_messages
from config import api_id, api_hash, username
from pars import get_messages
from bot import bot, send_new_requests

def main(client):
    messages = get_messages(client)
    requests = filter_messages(client, messages)
    send_new_requests(requests) 

def schedule_checker():
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client = TelegramClient(username, api_id, api_hash)
    client.start()
    schedule.every(1).hours.do(main, client=client)
    Thread(target=schedule_checker).start()
    bot.polling()
```

По логике, бот должен выслать сообщение, затем уйти в поллинг, а через час снова выслать сообщение. В этой конструкции вылезает ошибка: `RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1 (schedule_checker)'`. Я перепробовал все что мог, но все равно не получается.

Comment: https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parallel-execution.html#parallel-execution